# Hello everyone,Can I ask about sound processing when you press the button?

Tags: java, android

I use commands like this, but when I press repeatedly, I no longer hear the sound.

```java
private MediaPlayer mP;
private void ActionPlay() {

    BtnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.laclaclac);
            mP.start();
            mP.release();

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you press only once?

Comment: Try SoundPool instead of MedaiPlayer. It is better suited for repeatedly playing sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code and create a boolean value like this.

```
 private var isReleased = false

 @Synchronized
    private fun start(forceInSilence: Boolean): Boolean {
        if (isReleased) {
            return false
        }
        if (mP== null) {
            mP= MediaPlayer.create(ownersContext, myResSoundId)
            if (mP== null) {
                return false
            }
        }


        mP!!.start()

        return true
    }
```

and release the media player like this

```
@Synchronized
    fun release() {
        isReleased = true
        if (mP!= null) {
            mP!!.release()
            mP= null
        }
    }
```

So whenever you try to start and stop the sound on single button the call these methods for the functionalities.